# Django POST request in template (without form or a better solution)

Tags: python, html, css, django, templates

I have a shopping cart and I want to add an object to that shopping cart. There is a button which I press and when that happens I want the request to go through.

This is what I want to do in the POST request (When Button Is Pressed):

1. Check for Item with the same id as the product I pressed.
2. Create a CartItem with the same Item as the one I checked for above.
3. Add that cart item to my shopping cart linked to my profile. (Not started work yet)

Models:

```
class Item(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
info = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
price = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)

discount = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
discountPrice = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)

inStock = models.BooleanField(default=False)
imagefield = models.ImageField()
reviews = models.ManyToManyField(Review, blank=True, related_name="itemreview")

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Items'

def __str__(self):
    return "{name}".format(name=self.name)




class CartItem(models.Model):
item = models.ForeignKey(Item, blank=True, related_name="CartItem", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
price = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Cart Items'

def __str__(self):
    return self.item.name

def get_total_item_price(self):
    return self.quantity * self.item.price




class ShoppingCart(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
items = models.ManyToManyField(CartItem, blank=True, related_name="orderitem")

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Shopping Carts'

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username

def get_total(self):
    total = 0
    for cart_item in self.items.all():
        total += cart_item.get_total_item_price()
    return total


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_data(sender, update_fields, created, instance, **kwargs):
if created:
    user = instance
    profile = ShoppingCart.objects.create(user=user)
```

Views and urls:

```
def add_to_cart(request, item_id):
if request.method == 'POST':

    #create a cartitem
    selectedItem = Item.objects.filter(id=item_id)
    theQuantity = 1
    thePrice = selectedItem.price
    cartItem = CartItem(quantity=theQuantity, price=thePrice)
    cartItem.save()
    cartItem.item.add(selectedItem)

    #add that cartitem to the cart

    return redirect('landing-page')



urlpatterns = [
  path('', views.landingPage, name='landing-page'),
  path('product/<int:itemID>', views.singleProduct, name='singleProduct'),
  path('cart', views.shoppingCart, name='cart'),

  path('add-to-cart/<int:item_id>', views.add_to_cart, name="addToCart"),
  path('quantity-up/<int:cartitem_id>', views.change_quantity_up, name="quantity-upp"),
  path('quantity-down/<int:cartitem_id>', views.change_quantity_down, name="quantity-down"),
]
```

This is how I made the request and inside the html its a button with an a href="{% url 'addToCart' item.id %}"

[image]

html:

```
    <a class="button primary-btn" href="{% url 'addToCart' item.id %}">Add to Cart</a>
```

Comment: Your button is a link sending a GET request, and your view only processes POST requests (if it gets a GET request, since there's no `else` clause, it returns `None` as the error says).

Comment: yes I usually do everything in a form, but now I wanna do it in a button, how do I make this a post?

Comment: by using a button in a form...

Comment: Can you give aaa example, I tried that yesterday but I did not get it to work :)

Comment: Make a form where every input is predefined with type="hidden". Then let your action button be the submit button for the form.

Comment: then show us what you tried and we can help you further from there. You don't necessarily need a hidden input if you set the "action" attribute of your form to the same url as your current <a> button, since that includes the item id.